# will thumb also get callus on strumming guitar

Tags: guitar, chords, strumming

I am following a guitar tutorial series. The teacher wants me to use thumb for strumming for now and I am following that. It is working great but yesterday I played for hours and now my skin is going off from thumb. Should I keep playing with this or should I stop?

I know that I will get callus on chord finger tips, but how about strumming thumb?

Will it turn into callus? or it will get bad because the more I am playing, the more skin is going off, flesh is turning a little red, and it is hurting a little.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a joke:

MAN: Doctor, I get a shooting pain when I raise my arm like this.
DOCTOR: So don't raise your arm like that!

Seriously, this is the simple answer to avoid so many performance injuries. If something hurts, stop. Maybe the pain tells you you're doing something wrong, but maybe it just means you're doing the right thing but too much of it. Even the best technique is subject to the limits of the human body.

Especially when it comes to calluses: a callus is the skin's response to irritation. If you do small periods of irritation, repeated frequently over a long period of time, it forms a callus; if you do a long period of irritation over a short period of time you get a blister or wound.

I'm not going to address whether your technique is correct, but regardless, shorten your practice session, and maybe change up what you're doing, doing some pick strumming or other exercises to give your thumb a break. In fact, you'll want to stop thumb-strumming entirely until that heals a bit. You can try a "liquid bandage" product to protect it and still have some flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Some calluses are unavoidable, but they also come a lot from improper technique or using too much force. If you are a beginner and suddenly made an hours-long playing session, perhaps you overdid. You won't get anything good from tearing your skin more.

Check your technique. Does this part of your thumb come in contact with the string when you strum down, or up? You may try to use instead the softer, meatier part of the thumb for the down strokes, or the nail for the up strokes.

Comment: This is mostly the result of up strum, because I have been playing UUDU. So, this is not progress on callus and I have injured myself instead as I understand from your answer.

Comment: I went back and checked, the teacher is asking for this exact spot for up strum.

Comment: Here, I can see, he is using also the same spot for up strum that I have injured. https://youtu.be/-cBkIXaZoUI?t=83 What I am trying to say is that my technique is not wrong, it was probably overdoing it.

Comment: @EresDev Note he says to use the part of the thumb with the flesh for the up strum. And more importantly, he says you should brush the strings lightly, and use this technique to get less loud sound. But I can believe that even if you do it correctly, but for too long, you may hurt yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My initial answer was `Short answer: the instructor is wrong.`

But I've looked back over the video again, I'm not sure he's instructing you to use the knuckle, I think he's using the bit of skin basically where the nail meets the skin.

[image]

I subscribe to the idea that there is no absolute wrong/right technique when playing, we all find our own path and our own style. But I have never seen anyone in real life play for any sustained amount of time with their thumb knuckle. As you get more comfortable you will naturally find you can use more or less skin/nail to adjust the attack and tone of the strum.

Although, doing anything for hours is going to rub :O

Comment: Yes,I wasn't sure about the exact spot. This is helpful. I did it for hours because I was finally able to play my first song after months of learning (7 months). I was loving it so much that I kept going.

Comment: Bravo  keep it up, consistency is key 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this technique, and BTW I'm a bassist, finger-style and often play in Metal bands so I'm used to intensive playing sessions.

There's a balance to find for training/rehersal sessions, for which you'll get to know your limits better with time. There are various degrees of "callousness" for your fingers, with repeated training, the skin becomes generally harder (which I personnally look for to get more attack in the sound) or if too intensive can form a more localized callous (a very hard part surrounded by soft skin) which is not that great.

You usually want to acquire the callousness gradually to avoid a very hard bump with soft skin around, which can produce inconsistent sound or catch the strings. Above all, you want to avoid blisters, that will form this small hard bump if you insist on it. If you get a blister, stop playing until it heals.

You can benefit from changing techniques in between, for example start to use a pick of more classical arpeggio style when it gets painful. You want to build your strength gradually, it's the same with your muscles, don't get to the point you get hurt, or else it can take days to recover. Balance is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Find what works for you. I developed a technique where I put my thumb on my index finger - down uses the nail on the index finger, strumming up uses the thumb nail. Incorporating wrist movement rather than only arm makes the movement more fluid and natural. No calluses on that hand. That works for me - experiment and find what works best for you.

Answer (score -1):

Can't see any point in not using a pick (plectrum). Used properly, feathering either way, will give a different tone, but we don't know if that's a factor. But certainly it will stop your thumb from being damaged.

And a callus on your thumb will only be a hinderance, as it will start to catch on some strums. As already mentioned, it's the body's way of dealing with excess wear, which actually shouldn't happen. Some players have them as sort of 'badges of honour', others never get them. I submit they're a sign of excessive playing, bad technique, or badly set up instrument.

Let the thumb heal and play more gently, and for less time, and you'll find your happy balance. And don't believe everything on the 'net..!

Comment: Usual callous dv! With no explanation! Don't be shy!

Comment: I wasn’t the down voter, but… this doesn’t answer the question, goes against the teacher's instruction without any idea why they might asked for thumb strumming and the style is kind of condescending.